# Is it possible to make a recursive query with the following conditions in POSTGRESQL?

Tags: postgresql, recursive-query

I have a hierarchy in my table contacts. Each contact have column state_id which related with table contact_state (contact_id). There is a column is_top in contact_state table.

I need to write 2 queries:
Select COUNT recursively all children (parent column is parent_id) from contacts where the contact_state is_top is false. So if the child have state_id.contact_state is false, we need to looking for his children while the subchild.state_id.contact_state not be is true.

For this search I use this query:

```
with recursive hierarchy as (
select contact.id
from contacts contact join contact_state state1 on contact.state_id = state1.id and contact.parent_id = 45 and state1.is_top = false
union all
select recursive_contact.id
from contacts recursive_contact
inner join contact_state recursive_contact_state on recursive_contact.state_id = recursive_contact_state.id and recursive_contact_state.is_top = false inner join hierarchy on hierarchy.id = recursive_contact.parent_id
)
select count(*) from hierarchy;
```

But I don't understand at all how I can do this:
SELECT all children with state_id.is_top = true + go inside all children with state_id.is_top = false (recursively) until don't get the child with state_id.is_top = true (count only them + first level depth children with state_id.is_top = true)?
Is it possible?

If it will be much easier the option available:
Check only all children with state_id.is_top = false (recursively) until don't get the child with state_id.is_top = true (count only them + first level depth children with state_id.is_top = true)?
The first-level children I can easily add later

**UPD**:

database scema:

```
CREATE TABLE contacts (
id INT PRIMARY KEY, 
name TEXT,
parent_id INT,
state_id INT
);
CREATE TABLE contact_state (
id INT PRIMARY KEY, 
name TEXT,
is_top BOOL
);
```

demo data:

```
INSERT INTO contact_state VALUES(1, 'STATE #1', TRUE);
INSERT INTO contact_state VALUES(2, 'STATE #2', FALSE);
INSERT INTO contact_state VALUES(3, 'STATE #3', TRUE);
INSERT INTO contact_state VALUES(4, 'STATE #4', FALSE);

INSERT INTO contacts VALUES(1, 'A1', NULL, 2);
  INSERT INTO contacts VALUES(2, 'A2', 1, 1);
    INSERT INTO contacts VALUES(3, 'A3', 2, 2);
      INSERT INTO contacts VALUES(4, 'A4', 3, 3);

  INSERT INTO contacts VALUES(5, 'B2', 1, 4);
    INSERT INTO contacts VALUES(6, 'B3', 5, 2);
      INSERT INTO contacts VALUES(7, 'B4', 6, 1);
        INSERT INTO contacts VALUES(8, 'B5', 7, 3);

    INSERT INTO contacts VALUES(9,  'BB3', 5, 1);
      INSERT INTO contacts VALUES(10, 'BB4', 9, 1);

  INSERT INTO contacts VALUES(11, 'C2', 1, 4);
    INSERT INTO contacts VALUES(12, 'C3', 11, 3);

    INSERT INTO contacts VALUES(13, 'CC3', 11, 2);

  INSERT INTO contacts VALUES(14, 'D2', 1, 2);

  INSERT INTO contacts VALUES(15, 'E2', 1, 3);
```

Expected output:
5 (if use count) or ids: 2,7,9,12,15

Comment: Add Schema of your tables, sample data and expected output in your question.

Comment: @AkhileshMishra, I updated the question with this data

Comment: Please correct the input for `contact_state ` table

Comment: Can you please write what is wrong?
I use this service and it doesn't throw me an error http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8260aa
Or can you please follow this link and test there?

Comment: @AkhileshMishra I found the issue, sorry. Now it is fixed

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you have solved your problem, please consider answering your question so others can benefit.